# Simple shiny audio file example does not render

Tags: shiny

I'm having some difficulty with even the basic set-up for audio and video tags in *shiny*. It seems like the files are in the correct locations, however no output is being rendered and many of the other inputs (such as displaying controls) are ignored.

Here is a simple reproducible example. In the working directory where this source file is stored I also have a `www/clip.mp3` file (any file will do to replicate this issue).

```
library(shiny)

app <- list(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    textOutput('text'),
    tags$audio(src = "clip.mp3", type = "audio/mp3", 
               autoplay = TRUE, controls = TRUE)
)
), 
    server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        output$text <- renderText({
            c(getwd(), file.exists(paste0(getwd(), '/www/clip.mp3')))
            })
    })
)
runApp(app)
```

For me, the output shows `working/dir/path TRUE`, but nothing else. It looks like everything is in the correct position according to the documentation (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html), yet nothing is being rendered for the audio tag (even the requested controls).

Answer (score 3):

Everything is fine with your program. The only problem I found was running it with the RStudio viewer, but after launching it on a new window with Chrome everything works well. Also, as an advice, you could use the `addResourcePath` function to use a different directory instead of the /www. See the example below.

```R
addResourcePath("audio", "c:/temp") 

library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    tags$audio(src = "audio/clip.mp3", type = "audio/mp3", 
               autoplay = TRUE, controls = TRUE)
  )), 
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  })
))
```

Comment: Thanks, the point about Rstudio made sense and as initially throwing me off. You're right when launched in a true-blue browser your example works fine. Mine still does not run though unless I explicitly add `addResourcePath("www", "path/to/www")`, and use `www/clip.mp3`....which is odd, because I assumed this was in the path by default. Otherwise, only the controls are shown but the mp3 file is not playable.