# R flexdashboard: How to embed a video with a reactive value in file path?

Tags: r, shiny, html5-video, flexdashboard

I've got a [flexdashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/), and I need to embed a few videos.

With a static file path, it's pretty straightforward:

```
tags$video(
    src = "sample.mp4",
    type = "video/mp4",
    width = 1280, height = 720,
    controls = "controls"
)
```

But I can't figure out how to embed a video with a file path that includes an input/reactive value. This doesn't work:

```
renderUI({
    req(rv())

    tags$video(
        src = rv(),
        type = "video/mp4",
        width = 1280, height = 720,
        controls = "controls"
    )
})
```

Here's an Rmd file with both examples:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column
------

### Static
```{r}
tags$video(
    src = "sample.mp4",
    type = "video/mp4",
    width = 1280, height = 720,
    controls = "controls"
)
```

Column
------
```{r}
rv <- reactive({ "sample.mp4" })
```

### Reactive
```{r}
renderUI({
    req(rv())

    tags$video(
        src = rv(),
        type = "video/mp4",
        width = 1280, height = 720,
        controls = "controls"
    )
})
```
````

Upon inspection, the "static" chunk generates this HTML:

```
<video src="file5450741f3ada_files/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1280" height="720" controls="controls"></video>
```

Wheres the "dynamic" chunk this:

```
<video src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1280" height="720" controls="controls"></video>
```

It looks like `tags$video` puts the file in a temporary folder, which doesn't happen when `src` argument is a reactive value and/or inside `renderUI`.

Any tips?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work". Are you sure the `input$date` is formatted correctly to produce the correct path? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Done. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: I thought I'd make it work using addResourcePath() as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39380988/17216 but it only worked on my local machine. When I tun the document on a shiny server I get a 404 error, i.e. the file isn't found.